# Erro “The requested URL could not be matched by routing” usando Apigility

Tags: php, api, zend-framework-2

Eu crie minha API com Apigility, fiz o deploy e tudo estava funcionando bem até que subi os arquivos a meu servidor (hospedagem). Uma vez subi os arquivos e accedi à ruta do projeto Apigility no meu servidor encontrei o seguinte erro:

`404 The requested URL could not be matched by routing`.

Não sei qual é o problema, espero que vocês possam me ajudar. 
Aqui está a [**url**](http://54.207.32.250/testca/public/index.php) para visualizar o erro no site, e abaixo segue meus códigos:

application.config.php

```
<?php
/**
 * @license   http://opensource.org/licenses/BSD-3-Clause BSD-3-Clause
 * @copyright Copyright (c) 2014 Zend Technologies USA Inc. (http://www.zend.com)
 */

return array(
    // Retrieve the list of modules for this application.
    'modules' => include __DIR__ . '/modules.config.php',
    // This should be an array of paths in which modules reside.
    // If a string key is provided, the listener will consider that a module
    // namespace, the value of that key the specific path to that module's
    // Module class.
    'module_listener_options' => array(
        'module_paths' => array(
            './module',
            './vendor'
        ),
        // Using __DIR__ to ensure cross-platform compatibility. Some platforms --
        // e.g., IBM i -- have problems with globs that are not qualified.
        'config_glob_paths' => array('config/autoload/{,*.}{global,local}.php'),
        'config_cache_key' => 'application.config.cache',
        'config_cache_enabled' => true,
        'module_map_cache_key' => 'application.module.cache',
        'module_map_cache_enabled' => true,
        'cache_dir' => 'data/cache/',
    )
);
```

module.config.php

```
<?php
return array(
    'service_manager' => array(
        'factories' => array(
            'Content_Analytics\\V1\\Rest\\Post\\PostResource' => 'Content_Analytics\\V1\\Rest\\Post\\PostResourceFactory',
        ),
        'abstract_factories' => array(
            0 => 'Zend\\Log\\LoggerAbstractServiceFactory',
        ),
    ),
    'router' => array(
        'routes' => array(
            'content_analytics.rest.post' => array(
                'type' => 'Segment',
                'options' => array(
                    'route' => '/posts[/:post_id]',
                    'defaults' => array(
                        'controller' => 'Content_Analytics\\V1\\Rest\\Post\\Controller',
                    ),
                ),
            ),
        ),
    ),
    'zf-versioning' => array(
        'uri' => array(
            0 => 'content_analytics.rest.post',
        ),
    ),
    'zf-rest' => array(
        'Content_Analytics\\V1\\Rest\\Post\\Controller' => array(
            'listener' => 'Content_Analytics\\V1\\Rest\\Post\\PostResource',
            'route_name' => 'content_analytics.rest.post',
            'route_identifier_name' => 'post_id',
            'collection_name' => 'post',
            'entity_http_methods' => array(
                0 => 'GET',
                1 => 'PATCH',
                2 => 'PUT',
                3 => 'DELETE',
            ),
            'collection_http_methods' => array(
                0 => 'GET',
                1 => 'POST',
            ),
            'collection_query_whitelist' => array(),
            'page_size' => 25,
            'page_size_param' => null,
            'entity_class' => 'Content_Analytics\\V1\\Rest\\Post\\PostEntity',
            'collection_class' => 'Content_Analytics\\V1\\Rest\\Post\\PostCollection',
            'service_name' => 'post',
        ),
    ),
    'zf-content-negotiation' => array(
        'controllers' => array(
            'Content_Analytics\\V1\\Rest\\Post\\Controller' => 'Json',
        ),
        'accept_whitelist' => array(
            'Content_Analytics\\V1\\Rest\\Post\\Controller' => array(
                0 => 'application/vnd.content_analytics.v1+json',
                1 => 'application/hal+json',
                2 => 'application/json',
            ),
        ),
        'content_type_whitelist' => array(
            'Content_Analytics\\V1\\Rest\\Post\\Controller' => array(
                0 => 'application/vnd.content_analytics.v1+json',
                1 => 'application/json',
            ),
        ),
    ),
    'zf-hal' => array(
        'metadata_map' => array(
            'Content_Analytics\\V1\\Rest\\Post\\PostEntity' => array(
                'entity_identifier_name' => 'post_id',
                'route_name' => 'content_analytics.rest.post',
                'route_identifier_name' => 'post_id',
                'hydrator' => 'Zend\\Stdlib\\Hydrator\\ArraySerializable',
            ),
            'Content_Analytics\\V1\\Rest\\Post\\PostCollection' => array(
                'entity_identifier_name' => 'post_id',
                'route_name' => 'content_analytics.rest.post',
                'route_identifier_name' => 'post_id',
                'is_collection' => true,
            ),
        ),
    ),
    'controllers' => array(
        'factories' => array(
            'Content_Analytics\\V1\\Rpc\\Post\\Controller' => 'Content_Analytics\\V1\\Rpc\\Post\\PostControllerFactory',
            'Content_Analytics\\V1\\Rpc\\Posts\\Controller' => 'Content_Analytics\\V1\\Rpc\\Posts\\PostsControllerFactory',
        ),
    ),
    'zf-rpc' => array(),
    'zf-content-validation' => array(
        'Content_Analytics\\V1\\Rest\\Post\\Controller' => array(
            'input_filter' => 'Content_Analytics\\V1\\Rest\\Post\\Validator',
        ),
    ),
    'input_filter_specs' => array(
        'Content_Analytics\\V1\\Rest\\Post\\Validator' => array(
            0 => array(
                'required' => true,
                'validators' => array(),
                'filters' => array(),
                'name' => 'key_api',
                'description' => 'Google API developer key',
            ),
            1 => array(
                'required' => true,
                'validators' => array(),
                'filters' => array(),
                'name' => 'post_id',
                'description' => 'Post ID',
                'continue_if_empty' => false,
            ),
            2 => array(
                'required' => true,
                'validators' => array(),
                'filters' => array(),
                'name' => 'title',
                'description' => 'Post Title',
            ),
            3 => array(
                'required' => true,
                'validators' => array(),
                'filters' => array(),
                'name' => 'date_publishing',
                'description' => 'Publication date of the post',
            ),
            4 => array(
                'required' => true,
                'validators' => array(),
                'filters' => array(),
                'name' => 'url',
                'description' => 'Post URL',
            ),
            5 => array(
                'required' => true,
                'validators' => array(),
                'filters' => array(),
                'description' => 'Post Author',
                'name' => 'author',
            ),
            6 => array(
                'required' => true,
                'validators' => array(),
                'filters' => array(),
                'description' => 'Category Post',
                'name' => 'category',
            ),
            7 => array(
                'required' => true,
                'validators' => array(),
                'filters' => array(),
                'description' => 'Average session duration in post',
                'name' => 'avg_sesionDuration',
            ),
            8 => array(
                'required' => true,
                'validators' => array(),
                'filters' => array(),
                'description' => 'Views of post',
                'name' => 'view',
            ),
            9 => array(
                'required' => false,
                'validators' => array(),
                'filters' => array(),
                'name' => 'socialcount_Facebook',
                'allow_empty' => true,
                'description' => 'Number of visualizations in the Facebook',
            ),
            10 => array(
                'required' => false,
                'validators' => array(),
                'filters' => array(),
                'name' => 'socialcount_Twitter',
                'allow_empty' => true,
                'description' => 'Number of visualizations in the Twitter',
            ),
            11 => array(
                'required' => false,
                'validators' => array(),
                'filters' => array(),
                'name' => 'socialcount_Linkedin',
                'allow_empty' => true,
                'description' => 'Number of visualizations in the Linkedin',
            ),
            12 => array(
                'required' => false,
                'validators' => array(),
                'filters' => array(),
                'name' => 'socialcount_Reddit',
                'allow_empty' => true,
                'description' => 'Number of visualizations in the Reddit',
            ),
            13 => array(
                'required' => false,
                'validators' => array(),
                'filters' => array(),
                'name' => 'socialcount_StumbleUpon',
                'allow_empty' => true,
                'description' => 'Number of visualizations in the Stumble Upon',
            ),
            14 => array(
                'required' => false,
                'validators' => array(),
                'filters' => array(),
                'name' => 'socialcount_GooglePlus',
                'allow_empty' => true,
                'description' => 'Number of visualizations in the Google Plus',
            ),
            15 => array(
                'required' => false,
                'validators' => array(),
                'filters' => array(),
                'name' => 'socialcount_Pinterest',
                'allow_empty' => true,
                'description' => 'Number of visualizations in the Pinterest',
            ),
            16 => array(
                'required' => false,
                'validators' => array(),
                'filters' => array(),
                'name' => 'socialcount_Flattr',
                'allow_empty' => true,
                'description' => 'Number of visualizations in the Flattr',
            ),
            17 => array(
                'required' => false,
                'validators' => array(),
                'filters' => array(),
                'name' => 'socialcount_XING',
                'allow_empty' => true,
                'description' => 'Number of visualizations in the Xing',
            ),
            18 => array(
                'required' => false,
                'validators' => array(),
                'filters' => array(),
                'name' => 'update_date',
                'description' => 'Update data post',
                'allow_empty' => true,
            ),
            19 => array(
                'required' => true,
                'validators' => array(),
                'filters' => array(),
                'name' => 'total_social_count',
                'description' => 'Total social impact of post',
                'allow_empty' => false,
            ),
        ),
    ),
);
```

module.php

```
<?php
namespace Content_Analytics;

use ZF\Apigility\Provider\ApigilityProviderInterface;
use Content_Analytics\V1\Rest\Post\PostEntity;
use Content_Analytics\V1\Rest\Post\PostMapper;
use Zend\Db\TableGateway\TableGateway;
use Zend\Db\ResultSet\ResultSet;

class Module implements ApigilityProviderInterface
{
    public function getConfig()
    {
        return include __DIR__ . '/../../config/module.config.php';
    }

    public function getServiceConfig()
    {
      return array(
        'factories' => array(
          'contentanalyticsTableGateway' =>  function ($sm) {
            $dbAdapter = $sm->get('db');
            $resultSetPrototype = new ResultSet();
            $resultSetPrototype->setArrayObjectPrototype(new PostEntity());
            return new TableGateway('ca_blog_post', $dbAdapter, null, $resultSetPrototype);
          },
          'Content_Analytics\V1\Rest\Post\PostMapper' => function ($sm)
          {
              $tableGateway = $sm->get('contentanalyticsTableGateway');
              return new PostMapper($tableGateway);
          }
        ),
      );
    }

    public function getAutoloaderConfig()
    {
        return array(
            'ZF\Apigility\Autoloader' => array(
                'namespaces' => array(
                    __NAMESPACE__ => __DIR__,
                ),
            ),
        );
    }
}
```